# Update rows from multiple tables and

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project where I need to update 2 tables in a query.

I am doing this

```
UPDATE ward_beds a, ipd_patient_list b 
SET 
a.occupation_status = 'empty', 
b.patient_status = 'Discharged' 
WHERE 
a.ward_id = b.ward_id AND b.patient_id = '4' 
AND 
b.appointment_id = '6' AND b.ward_id = '1'
```

so far it is working, now I want to update this

```
b.patient_status = 'Discharged'
```

on the row which is the last in all matching rows. I tried to put this

```
ORDER BY b.row_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

but it shows

```
#1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY
```

error. How should I do it?

Comment: You won't ever use an `UPDATE` _and_ an `ORDER BY`.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You can make inner query for table B with `ORDER BY`.Then simply try your currently running query.

Comment: using `Having b.row_id=max(b.row_id)`

Comment: @JayShankarGupta with this line also it gives syntax error same as above.

Comment: @Stuart I want to update a row from one table based on the ward ID and then based on same ward ID I want to update one row from another table. But in the first table, there is only one matching row, so it is easy, in second table there are at least 10 matching rows. I want to update only the 10th row. And not touch the first 9 rows at all. SO I used to order by DESC and then limit one. But it does not work.

Comment: It sounds like your scema does not represent the reality is trying to describe (or your solution does not match the intended usage of the schema) particularly if the differentiator between the states is based on the sequence of a **surrogate** key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use limit in this kind of update 
but you could seach for the correct id using a subquery and join to the others tables

```
  UPDATE ward_beds a
  INNER JOIN (
    select  ward_id, max(row_id)  last_id 
    from ipd_patient_list
    group by ward_id
  ) t on t.ward_id = a.ward_id
  INNER JOIN ipd_patient_list b  ON a.ward_id = b.ward_id
        AND b.patient_id = '4' 
          AND b.appointment_id = '6' 
            AND b.ward_id = '1' 
              AND b.row_id = t.last_id
SET a.occupation_status = 'empty', 
    b.patient_status = 'Discharged'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought of doing it, but lack of querying skill kept me from it! This is working perfectly!